# cakephp pagination Urls - routes.php adress are not used since i added a Price Filter

Tags: cakephp, filter, pagination

Hello ich have a Problem with my Pagination .
The numbers() just show the correct url if my price filter is not clicked...
if it is user there is /price:25-50/ in the url and the links created by the numbers() operation go back to using controller and action url....

Comment: Could you please show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Named parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/view/947/Named-parameters) section of cookbook:

> When making custom routes, a common pitfall is that using named parameters will break your custom routes. In order to solve this you should inform the Router about which parameters are intended to be named parameters. Without this knowledge the Router is unable to determine whether named parameters are intended to actually be named parameters or routed parameters, and defaults to assuming you intended them to be routed parameters. To connect named parameters in the router use `Router::connectNamed()`.

```
Router::connectNamed(array('price'));
```

Comment: i mean the rest works, i get a working url, the named params are used also, just the route rewrite to a "nice" url is no more used....

Comment: just i had to add this...Router::connectNamed(array('preis'), array('default' => true));